# Convert list of pandas series to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a list of rows that I want to convert to a data frame. Each element of a list is of type pandas Series. How can I convert it?

The sample data is like this:

````
GROUP_NUM                                                      61
PID_LOCATION    [(-111.58903, 33.252235), (-111.59659, 33.2470...)]
PROJECT_KEYS    224033,20542,224037,224039,224040,224041,16610...
PROJECT_NAME    name1...
ZIPCODE         xxxxx
DEFAULT_GEOM    MULTIPOLYGON (((-111.645291932 33.215893723,-1...
Name: 8468, dtype: object, aoi_attr_type_id
aoi_id                       ffeaac-cb85-447f-a367-b37558e452
GROUP_NUM                                                      60
PID_LOCATION                      [(u'-117.40181', u'34.542542')]
PROJECT_KEYS                                               204222
PROJECT_NAME                                          xyz
ZIPCODE                                                     92xxx
DEFAULT_GEOM    MULTIPOLYGON(((-117.416929337 34.557322993,-11...)))
Name: 8469, dtype: object, aoi_attr_type_id
aoi_id                       ff69ae-d61a-4776-af1d-5da73eb05a
GROUP_NUM                                                      63
PID_LOCATION    [(-97.348755, 32.587357), (-97.33046, 32.57823...)]
PROJECT_KEYS                     218461,181794,209575,59540,15239
PROJECT_NAME    some_name2
ZIPCODE                                               yyyyy
DEFAULT_GEOM    MULTIPOLYGON (((-97.332423163 32.571877745,-97...)))
Name: 8470, dtype: object]```

I tried this and get the following error: 

    ipdb> res_df=pd.DataFrame.from_items(merged_polygons)
    *** ValueError: too many values to unpack

FYI
ipdb> type(merged_polygons[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
````

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame(merged_polygons)` not work? Where `merged_polygons` is a list of `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this from here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1494

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([(s.name, s) for s in merged_polygons]).T`

Answer (score 3):

You may use `pd.concat` to make it more simple. Every series will be a column in `df`

```
df = pd.concat(merged_polygons, axis=1)
```

If you want every series as a row in `df`, just add `T`

```
df = pd.concat(merged_polygons, axis=1).T

or 

df = pd.DataFrame(merged_polygons)
```